# Grails - RuntimeException on every controller

Tags: grails

I am getting this exception on every controller. Than application halts for some time and than it runs successfully. I am using `grails 3.1.9` and `java 1.8_0_91`. I have checked every thing and it seems fine. I have tested it with two application and error stays same.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Reloading agent exited via exception, please raise a jira
        at org.springsource.loaded.agent.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:110)
        at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.ResolverUtil.addIfMatching(ResolverUtil.java:384)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.ResolverUtil.loadImplementationsInDirectory(ResolverUtil.java:286)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.ResolverUtil.loadImplementationsInDirectory(ResolverUtil.java:284)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.ResolverUtil.loadImplementationsInDirectory(ResolverUtil.java:284)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.ResolverUtil.findInPackage(ResolverUtil.java:204)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginRegistry.loadFromPackage(PluginRegistry.java:222)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginManager.collectPlugins(PluginManager.java:152)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:202)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:231)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:496)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:566)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:582)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:217)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:152)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:551)
        at com.asklytics.services.admin.AdminInfluxDBInstanceProvisioningService.<clinit>(AdminInfluxDBInstanceProvisioningService.java:18)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1075)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
        at org.grails.spring.beans.factory.OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.instantiate(OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:89)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:55)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:374)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:363)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at analyticsapp.Application.main(Application.groovy:14)
Caused by: org.springsource.loaded.ReloadException: Problem defining class com..asklytics.analytics.LogoutController__I
        at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.defineClass(TypeRegistry.java:1310)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ReloadableType.rewriteCallSitesAndDefine(ReloadableType.java:941)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ReloadableType.<init>(ReloadableType.java:173)
        at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.addType(TypeRegistry.java:1108)
        at org.springsource.loaded.agent.SpringLoadedPreProcessor.preProcess(SpringLoadedPreProcessor.java:335)
        at org.springsource.loaded.agent.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:107)
        ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.defineClass(TypeRegistry.java:1302)
        ... 67 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com//asklytics/analytics/LogoutController__I (wrong name: com/asklytics/analytics/LogoutController__I)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
        ... 71 more
```

Comment: Two grails applications that are running customised code that has a problem. This issue relates to what is within your app and you then translating / READING the actual error and trying to figure out why it hasn't worked. for example : `com.asklytics.services.admin.AdminInfluxDBInstanceProvisioningService`  and `Caused by: org.springsource.loaded.ReloadException: Problem defining class com..asklytics.analytics.LogoutController__I` are not as part of a default grails install application. please create a brand new grails app with nothing then compare run-app vs your 2 broken apps

Comment: you should upgrade your grails version, it's a problem in one of spring boot dependencies